# too many logged information on log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have some mvc4 application where I want to log when admin user is logged, when bad login is happen, crud operations, etc. Now everything works but I cannot see tree from the forest :) Too many information is logged, so I want to remove everything but my info which I explicitly set at contoller with `log.Info("User is succ. login");` etc.

```
2013-03-27 20:25:11,285 [40] INFO NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - mapping collection: Domain.Model.Property.Photos -> Photo
2013-03-27 20:25:11,285 [40] INFO NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing one-to-one association property references
2013-03-27 20:25:11,285 [40] INFO NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing foreign key constraints
```

and bellow is over100 lines like this.

I was thinking that this is maybe I set up log xml configuration at application_startup

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

and root appender is registered like this

```
<root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

So again, how to remove all this mapping and other information and log only my explicit log information with log.Info("some info");

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what information is logged by applying a conversionPattern to the appender.

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\Log\log.log"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```